# Create a function with multiple parameters in R

Tags: r, function, plot

I want to compute the following functions :

[image: equation]

[image]

here, g(x) is the density function of a distribution. I want to compute this function for several distributions. In addition, I use the library fitdistrplus.

To create g, I use the function do.call this way :

```
g<-function(x) {do.call(paste("d",i,sep=""),c(list(x=x),fti$estimate))}
```

fti$estimate contains the parameters of the distribution i.

G(x) is the cumulative distribution computed this way :

```
G<-function(x) {do.call(paste("p",i,sep=""),c(list(q=x),fti$estimate))}
```

I compute f(x) this way :

```
f<function(n,x) {n*g(x)*(1-G(x))^(n-1)
```

At last, I compute h(x) this way :

```
h<- function(n) {integrate(function(x) {x*f(n,x)},0,Inf)}
```

However, I can't plot these functions, I get the following errors :

```
1: In n*g(x):
Longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In (1-G(x))^(n-1):
Longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In x*f(n,x) :
Longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Beyond, if I juste want to plot f(n,x), I get this error :

```
Error in list(x=x) :'x' is missing
```

The minimal snipset I have is the following

```
#i can be "exp" "lnorm" "norm" etc...
for( i in functionsName) {
    png(paste(fileBase,"_",i,"_","graphics.png",sep=""))
    plot.new()

    fti<-fitdist(data, i)
    plotdist(data,i, para=as.list(fti[[1]]))
    #fti is a datatable or datafram
    #fti$estimate looks like this :
    # meanlog    sdlog 
    #8.475449 1.204958 

    #g
    pdf<-function(x) {do.call(paste("d",i,sep=""), c(list(x=x),fti$estimate))}  
#G
    cdf<-function(x) do.call(paste("p",i,sep=""), c(list(q=x),fti$estimate))


#f
    minLaw<- function(n,x) {n*pdf(x)*(1-cdf(x))^(n-1)}
    #h
    minExpectedValue<-function(n) {integrate(function(x) {x*minLaw(n,x)},0,Inf)}

    #these 2 following lines give an error
    plot(minExpectedValue)
    plot(minLaw)

    dev.off()
}
```

Comment: What is the exact line of code you're running that gives the error? Also, what is `i`, and what are the values in `fti`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to do some reverse engineering to figure out your *d1*, *q1* etc calls, but I think this is how you do it. Perhaps the original problem lies in a function call like *f(n=2:3, x=1:9)*; in such a call *n* should be a single value, not a vector of values.

Even if length of *x* was a multiple of *n* length, the output would most likely not be what you really wanted.
If you try to give *n* a vector form, you might end up in a recycled (false) output:

```
> print(data.frame(n=2:3, x=1:6))
- n x
1 2 1
2 3 2
3 2 3
4 3 4
5 2 5
6 3 6
```

where *x* would be evaluated with *n=2* at point *x=1*, *n=3* at point *x=2* etc. What you really would've wanted is something in the lines of:

```
> print(expand.grid(x=1:5, n=2:3))
-  x n
1  1 2
2  2 2
3  3 2
4  4 2
5  5 2
6  1 3
7  2 3
8  3 3
9  4 3
10 5 3
```

You could do this by calling separately for each *n* value:

```
lapply(2:3, FUN=function(n) (f(n, x=1:5)))
#[[1]]
#[1] 0.0004981910 0.0006066275 0.0007328627 0.0008786344 0.0010456478
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 0.0007464956 0.0009087272 0.0010974595 0.0013152213 0.0015644676
```

Did you use the same *fti* for all the distribution fits, even though it should've been different? Or does the *i* in *fti* refer to index *i* and it was a list of fits in form of *ft[[i]]?*

Below is a wrapper function, which is called separately for each *n*-value (and distribution *i*):

```
wrapper <- function(i, x, n, fti){
    # As was provided by OP
    g<-function(x) {do.call(paste("d",i,sep=""),c(list(x=x),fti$estimate))}

    G<-function(x) {do.call(paste("p",i,sep=""),c(list(q=x),fti$estimate))}
    # does the i in fti refer to fit of i:th distribution, i.e. should it be a list where i:th location in ft is i:th distribution estimates?

    f<-function(n,x) {n*g(x)*(1-G(x))^(n-1)}
    # was missing a '-' and a '}'

    h<- function(n) {integrate(function(x) {x*f(n,x)},0,Inf)}

    list(gres = g(x), Gres = G(x), fres = f(n,x), hres = h(n))
}

# Example data
require("fitdistrplus")
data(groundbeef)
serving <- groundbeef$serving

# Gumbel distribution
d1 <- function(x, a, b) 1/b*exp((a-x)/b)*exp(-exp((a-x)/b))
p1 <- function(q, a, b) exp(-exp((a-q)/b))
q1 <- function(p, a, b) a-b*log(-log(p))

fti1 <- fitdist(serving, "1", start=list(a=10, b=10))
#> fti1$estimate
#       a        b 
#56.95893 29.07871

# Normal distribution

# dnorm, pnorm and qnorm are available in the default environment
d2 <- dnorm
p2 <- pnorm
q2 <- qnorm

fti2 <- fitdist(serving, "2", start=list(mean=0, sd=1))
#> fti2$estimate
#    mean       sd 
#73.67743 35.92581

# Sequence of x-values
xs <- seq(-100, 100, by=1)

print((resultdist1n2 <- wrapper(i=1, x=xs, n=2, fti=fti1))$hres)
print((resultdist1n3 <- wrapper(i=1, x=xs, n=3, fti=fti1))$hres)
print((resultdist2n2 <- wrapper(i=2, x=xs, n=2, fti=fti2))$hres)
print((resultdist2n3 <- wrapper(i=2, x=xs, n=3, fti=fti2))$hres)

plot(xs, resultdist1n2$fres, col=1, type="l", ylim=c(0,0.025), xlab="x", ylab="f(n, x)")
points(xs, resultdist1n3$fres, col=2, type="l")
points(xs, resultdist2n2$fres, col=3, type="l")
points(xs, resultdist2n3$fres, col=4, type="l")
legend("topleft", legend=c("Gamma (i=1) n=2", "Gamma (i=1) n=3", "Normal (i=2) n=2", "Normal (i=2) n=3"), col=1:4, lty=1)
```

[image: f-functions with different i and n]

And the results of your desired *h* as found in resultdist1n2$hres etc:

```
h(n=2) for distribution i=1:
53.59385 with absolute error < 0.00022
h(n=3) for distribution i=1:
45.23146 with absolute error < 4.5e-05
h(n=2) for distribution i=2:
53.93748 with absolute error < 1.1e-05
h(n=3) for distribution i=2:
44.06331 with absolute error < 2e-05
```

**EDIT**: Here's how one uses the *lapply* function to call for each of the vector of *n* values *0<=n<=256*:

```
ns <- 0:256
res1 <- lapply(ns, FUN=function(nseq) wrapper(i=1, x=xs, n=nseq, fti=fti1))
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(-100,100), ylim=c(0, 0.05))
box(); axis(1); axis(2); title(xlab="x", ylab="f(n,x)", main="f(n,x) for gamma (i=1), n=0:256")
for(i in 1:length(ns)) points(xs, res1[[i]]$fres, col=rainbow(257)[i], type="l")
# perform similarly for the other distributions by calling with i=2, fti=fti2
# h as a function of n for dist i=1
plot(ns, unlist(lapply(res1, FUN=function(x) x$hres$value)), col=rainbow(257), xlab="n", ylab="h(n)", main="h(n) for gamma (i=1), n=0:256")
```

I would plot each distribution *i* separately like this.

[image: 0<=n<=256 plots]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know if you saw my edit, maybe you will understand better. However, I'm still stuck. The idea is to plot h(n) for every 0<=n<=256. It can't possible to just call h(n) ? I don't understand precisely the error. 
The idea of a wrapper is great ;)

Comment: The start of my post attempts to explain why your h(n) didn't work - I was posting as you edited. Both n and x cannot be vectors, and I think your code implicitly incorporated a vector for x values. I now edited my answer so that I show how you could test multiple n-values by calling each n value separately with the wrapper function. In essence, it is doing many calls: wrapper(i=1, x=xs, n=nseq[1], fti=fti1); wrapper(i=1, x=xs, n=nseq[2], fti=fti1), etc where nseq is your vector of n values 0:256. For each distribution I would perform this separately, so that I change the i and fti values.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This time I understand how does your example work. However, I obtain the following error : too many open devices. I don't plot anything right now just calling lapply !

Comment: I would guess it's plotting in the background and opening a new device for each value of n or then you have opened graphical devices with your plot.new and png calls that exist in your code (I only ran my own independent example due to not having your data). Try running few dev.off()'s to close down any possible png devices or restart your session. If your code has been interrupted due to an error it may be that there are a lot of open devices that were never closed due to code interruption.

Comment: An other error I get is the following : evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
Calls: wrapper -> minExpectedValue -> integrate

I use the following sequence xs<-(xmin, xmax,1) where xmin=50 and xmax = 60720.

I don't understand this error one more time, and especially, why youy didn't get this error.

I tried to use Vectorize() but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `plot` method for a function expects that the function will be vectorised. In other words, if given an argument of length N, it should return a vector of results also of length N.

Your `minExpectedValue` doesn't satisfy this; it expects that `n` will be a scalar, and returns a scalar. You can quickly fix this up with `Vectorize`. You also need to specify the name of the argument to plot over, in this case `n`.

```
minExpectedValue <- Vectorize(minExpectedValue)
plot(minExpectedValue, xname="n")
```

Comment: I tried this and I get an error :
evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length

Do you know why ?